# What do the numbers mean in the upper right hand side of the emulator?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8.1

I am very new to WP development and have created my first application. When I run it, I see some data printed vertically on the emulator Screen.

What are these, and what do they indicate?

[image] attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are performance counters for your app. Here is the image that describe them.

```
// Display the current frame rate counters.
// This is enabled by default in your app
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

These are for monitoring your app. Like frame rates etc.For more info check this [**Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967560(v=vs.105).aspx).

`Ctrl + F  "Enable frame rate counters"`

[image]
[(image source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg588380(v=vs.105).aspx)