# Understanding Memory Counters in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, performancecounter

Developing a Windows 8 Phone app.

I have noticed that there are these performance counters on the right hand-side of my device/emulator.

On my device the 3rd number - 35 (etc) is constantly displayed in a red font. On the emulator it is not (see image below).  I am not too concerned about that as I am sure the emulator is not a direct parallel to a real device. What I am concerned about is that it is red on my device. Should I be worried about this?

Also, on a side-note on a previous StackOverFlow question [What do the numbers mean in the upper right hand side of the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462867/what-do-the-numbers-mean-in-the-upper-right-hand-side-of-the-emulator)

There are 6 different numbers.

I only have 4.

So, is this the surface counter? That would make sense as i am updating my img controls.

Any enlightenment would be great.

[image]

sd

Comment: It is explained well in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.debugsettings.enableframeratecounter), 6 counters on Windows 8, 4 counters on 8.1.  So you are looking at "Sys fps".  35 seems okay, dropping below 30 is a problem.  Maybe the device wants you to do a bit better ;)